# Spark ar studio i try t build a simple filter but i have this problem on my console:ERROR: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, nodes, spark-ar-studio

when i try to run the console i have the following error on the spark ar studio console.
ERROR: undefined is not a function
{
"line": 13,
"column": 25,
"sourceURL": "script.js"
}

```
import {quiz} from './quiz.js'

const Scene =require('Scene')
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics')
const Materials = require('Materials')
const TouchGestures = require('TouchGestures')

const root = Scene.root

let question = root.find('question')
let counter = root.find('counter')
let next = root.find('next')


let a1= root.find('a1')
let a2= root.find('a2')
let a3= root.find('a3')
let a4= root.find('a4')

let mats = [ 
        Materials.get('answer_bg1'),
        Materials.get('answer_bg2'),
        Materials.get('answer_bg3'),
        Materials.get('answer_bg4')
]

let rects = [
    root.find('answer_bg1'),
    root.find('answer_bg2'),
    root.find('answer_bg3'),
    root.find('answer_bg4'),

]
 let answers =[]
 let righAnswers=[]
 
 let selected = 0
 let questionNumber=0
 
 let q = quiz[questionNumber]
 
 question.text=q.question
```

Comment: What part of the code throws the error?

Comment: You need to use async methods. Everything else should not work. Check the official website for info.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v85 of Spark AR Studio the current JavaScript APIs are deprecated in favor of asynchronous APIs.

This means some APIs will be deprecated and will need to be replaced in your projects. When creating new projects, new APIs should be used instead.

You can learn more about it here
[Scripting Javascript Promise In Spark AR For Beginners](https://www.gowaaa.com/post/scripting-javascript-promise-in-spark-ar-for-beginners)